# List of anonymous types

Tags: c#

I have a `List<MyObject>` that returns from a call to my repo. I need to return a JSON result to my DataTable. Just to test, I hardcode results, and this works when I return it to my UI.

```
var result = new[]
{
    new { name = "Craig", id="1" },
    new { name = "Melanie", id="2" }
};
```

Now I need to rather use the list I got back from my service call, but I'm not sure how to go through it, and create the same result type.

I tried this, but it's syntactically incorrect - but it's an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
var t = results.Select(x => x = new { name = x.ResultText, id = x.ItemId }).ToArray();
```

I can't do a `foreach`, can I? How can I iterate through the results of my service call, and build my response to go back to my UI.

Answer (score 3):

You won´t need to (and basically you can´t) *re-assign* `x` as you can´t change an enumeration while iterating it. Simply take the return-value from the `Select`-query and store it to a variable:

```
var t = results.Select(x => new { name = x.ResultText, id = x.ItemId }).ToArray();
```